# Wallpost problems?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Im trying to make wallpost from my fb app. My code (bellow) wont give eny erros but it just wont publish anything to wall. Can someone help me? =P

Application file (index.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1234567890', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>



<a href="#" onClick="postToFacebook()">Post to Facebook</a>

<script>
function postToFacebook() {
    var body = 'Reading Connect JS documentation';

    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { body: body, message: 'My message is ...' }, function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
      } else {
        alert('Post ID: ' + response);
      }
    });
}
</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : 'YOUR APP ID GOES HERE',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And channel file in server (channel.php):

```
 <?php
 $cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
 header("Pragma: public");
 header("Cache-Control: max-age=".$cache_expire);
 header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire) . ' GMT');
 ?>
 <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would like to see some simple example how to make wallpost from application :)

Comment: If you console.dir the response of the callback from the post command, what does it show?

Answer (score 1):

Why are You trying to init Facebook scripts twice?:)
Here's an example of a working code :
[How to get FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', ... to work?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3932880/how-to-get-fb-api-me-feed-post-to-work)
Mind You, the user needs to authorize the app first before You can make FB.api calls.
You can do that by using FB.login e.g:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/
and check if the user actually connected to Your app by using FBgetLoginStatus():
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/
Hope this helps

Comment: And why do i need to chec users connect status inside facebook app? Because if user isnt logged in FB he obviously cant publish anything to FB.

Comment: Wont work :/

Can someone please give me working code that posts something to wall? This gives me example about wallpost so i can develop my own app :/

It doesnt matter if wallpost comes PHP or JS but complete code will help me.

Comment: The mere fact of your page being inside of a facebook App doesn't mean that the user gave permissions to publish stuff:) You need to do that, there are some examples over here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/